# Border inside the element with space with the edge

Tags: html, css, image, border

How can I add a border to the element that's inside the element, and to have a space between it and the edge of the element? with CSS

something like this

[image]

Thank you

EDIT:
Can't use the image as a background, I want it to be an img element

Comment: how about making the picture as background?

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' not possible as the picture is changeable from the backend

Comment: is it okay for you to use positioning? like absolute or relative?

Comment: better use `position:absolute` for the bordered-box

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' I think it's OK to use 'relative'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a container/wrapper around the image.

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 2px #fff;
    z-index:1;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGZXN.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0zj3bc1g/3/)**

Comment: very smart solution using before, i liked that u didn't add extra html
thx !

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this as of now.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}
.border {
  height: 154px;
  width: 219px;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGZXN.png">
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice and clean, although i don't like adding an extra div, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make a div inside a div with the image as background. Give the div the Border and size you want. And because html and css sometimes works strange you maybe have to move the div over the image with negative margin.
Hope that helps you.

Comment: img is an inline selfclosing block, you should never add a block element within it

Comment: i know it's kind of an ugly solution but it works @tripleb

Comment: @tripleb I edited the answer. Is it better this way?

Comment: @M.Zuberbühler can't use a background image as the image is changeable from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/15/

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/zimwiki/images/0/00/Gir.png/revision/latest?cb=20130712225209" width="200" />
 <span></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  border: 5px solid gray;
}
span{
  position:relative;
  top:-200px;
  left:-188px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding:150px 80px 170px 80px;
}
```